# Очень медленно работает JPA в многопоточном варианте записи в БД

Tags: java, многопоточность, hibernate, jpa

настройки проперти

```
jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 50
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    my_basa:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 50
          order_inserts: true
          lob.non_contextual_creation: true
          generate_statistics: true


task:
     execution:
       pool:
          core-size: 100
          max-size: 100
          queue-capacity: 1000
          keep-alive: 120s
            await-termination: true
            allow-core-thread-timeout: false
          shutdown:
            await-termination-period: 5m
          thread-name-prefix: DiaSoftReplicatorThread-
```

разбиение коллекции на бачи и отправление каждого бача на запись в многопоточку

```
private void saveAllJdbcBatchCallable(List<MyDATA> source) {
        try {
            List<List< MyDATA >> partition = Lists.partition(source, batchSize);
            List<Callable<Void>> callables = partition.stream().map(sublist ->
                    (Callable<Void>) () -> {
                        saveDataToBD(sublist);
                        return null;
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            taskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().invokeAll(callables);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

метод записи в БД

```
public void saveDataToBD(List<MyDATA> source) {
        myJpaRepository.saveAll(source);
    }
```

вопрос в том, где то не верно настроена многопоточка или jpa в принципе не нуждается в многопоточке если используется batch_size.

Comment: Я на все 100 не уверен, но создаётся впечатление что не скофигурирован connection pool.

Comment: а где варианты можно посмотреть его правильной конфигурации?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573034/spring-boot-how-do-i-set-jdbc-pool-properties-like-maximum-number-of-connection

Comment: работает или не работает bulk insert в хибере очень сильно зависит от двух факторов: 1. если сущности новые, то как у них генерируются идентификаторы, если там `identity`, то ожидать производительности не стоит. 2. если происходит обновление существующих, то увы, в большинстве случаев необходимый merge перед сохранением всю производительность убивает

Comment: да вот у меня второй вариант

Comment: @pra_soul_owl нужен код. В действительности, если пайплайн такой, что вы изначально забираете данные из БД, как-то их модифицируете и сохраняете, то вполне возможно что вариант без потоков будет значительно быстрее, потому что другой поток - это другая транзакции, и, соответственно, паразитный merge.